# Blank output using feynmp package

Tags: miktex, output, feynmf, feynmp, feynmp-auto

Using all the code of `feynmp` package in my recent distribuition of MikTeX for W10 I have not see nothing. Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}
  \begin{fmfgraph}(110,60)
    \fmfleft{i1,i2}
    \fmfright{o1,o2}
    \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
    \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
    \fmf{photon}{v1,v2}
  \end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Log. file**:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.3) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.5.10)  10 MAY 2022 17:17
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**"C:/Users/sebys/OneDrive/Desktop/new question/Test3.tex"
(C:/Users/sebys/OneDrive/Desktop/new question/Test3.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-04-29>
(C:\Users\sebys\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\sebys\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(C:\Users\sebys\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks16
\inpenc@posthook=\toks17
)
(C:\Users\sebys\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/feynmf\feynmf.sty
Package: feynmf 1996/12/02 v1.08 LaTeX/Metafont Feynman Diagram Package (ohl)
\@outfmf=\write3
\fmfbuf@=\toks18
\c@fmfgraph=\count193
\grep@infile=\read2
\grep@outfile=\write4
)
(C:\Users\sebys\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdf
tex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-04-20 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count194
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
) (C:/Users/sebys/OneDrive/Desktop/new question\Test3.aux)
\openout1 = `Test3.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.

! Font \f@ynmf:feyngraph=feyngraph not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   \@interactionmode 
l.5 \begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}
                              
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.


feynmf: Files feyngraph.mf and feyngraph.tfm not found:
feynmf: This job will create feyngraph.mf, process it later with METAFONT
feynmf: and then reprocess this file. Don't worry about a harmless premature
feynmf: MakeTeXTFM that might have failed just a moment ago!
\openout3 = `feyngraph.mf'.

[1

{C:/Users/sebys/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}] (Test3.aux) 
) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 640 strings out of 478604
 11478 string characters out of 2842648
 301530 words of memory out of 3000000
 18866 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 469259 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 34i,5n,38p,198b,107s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,80000s
<C:/Users/sebys/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/c
mr10.pfb>
Output written on Test3.pdf (1 page, 14614 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 11 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Same result with `feynmp-auto` like usepackage.

Comment: Did you see this in your log file?  `\openout3 = feyngraph.mp
feynmp: File feyngraph.1 not found:
feynmp: Process feyngraph.mp with MetaPost and then reprocess this file.
`

Comment: There is a three stage compile process required for feynmp.  Run latex to produce a Metapost program; run `mpost` on that program to produce a graphic file; run latex again to include the graphic.  But you should be able to do all that *automatically* if you just change `\usepackage{feynmp}` to `\usepackage{feynmp-auto}`.

Comment: @Thruston Hi, I have done all that it is possible but it not works. There is a problem unknown ! Font \f@ynmf:feyngraph=feyngraph not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   \@interactionmode 
l.5 \begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}. I have tried also with \usepackage{feynmp-auto} but I not see nothing.

Comment: @Sebastiano When you tried `feynmp-auto`, did you make sure that Shell Escape was allowed? As far as I know, this package requires shell escape to launch some necessary commands during compilation (see page 2 of the package's documentation).

Comment: The log file errors are from `feynmf` package.  Don't use `feynmf` !

Comment: @Miyase What is Shell Escape? In December all works correctly on W7; now I not see nothing.

Comment: @Thruston Hi I have not used `feynmf`: see the MWE but `\usepackage{feynmp}` or with `\usepackage{feynmp-auto}` I not see nothing.

Comment: @Sebastiano Shell escape is a way for LaTeX to call external programs, and it's required for feynmp-auto. Since it's a security risk, it's possible that recent distributions disable this feature by default.

Comment: @Sebastiano If you're the same Sebastiano who answered the question in the link provided by samcarter above, you did configure your editor to enable shell escape in the past. Perhaps you lost your configuration and need to do it again?

Comment: @Miyase It is true. I have forgotten my old question and answer. My best regards.